# $k$-regular graph with $n=46$ existence

Tags: graph-theory

The condition for existence of a $k$-regular graph with $n$ nodes is : $n \geq k +1$ and $n \times k$ even. For $n=46$ and $k=3$ these two conditions are satisfied.

Nevertheless, I can't seem to plot/construct such a graph!

What am I doing wrong?

Idea of how to plot on Matlab: create a circle graph with $46$ nodes (so connect each $i$ with $i+1$) then connect nodes $i$ and $i+1$ respectively with $i+2$ and $i+3$, then jump $i+2$ and $i+3$ (because already degree $3$) and repeat.

Graph: (with zoom on node $45$ and $46$ of degree $2$ only! while all the other nodes have degree $3$)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is mainly creating 'clusters' of size $4$, say $k+1,k+2,k+3,k+4$, which look like a $K_4$ minus $\{k+1,k+4\}$. Then you combine these by the relations you described. Now, $45$ and $46$ do not belong to any such cluster, so they are just connected to one another and $45$ to $44$ and $46$ to 1.

This 'clustering' is mainly due to the fact that you skip one connection because the nodes are already of degree $3$. The construction would work for a graph with $n=4l$ nodes.

A way to create another $3$-regular graph would be creating a cycle and then connecting $k$ to $k+23$ for $k=1,...,23$.

Comment: thank you your suggestion (connect k to k+23)  works perfectly!